# UWP POST request like GET

Tags: post, uwp, httpclient

I need to send POST request from my UWP app. 
I read about it [here](http://kiewic.com/2014-10-23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync).

I use one shared `HttpClient`.

```
 private Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient;
```

Initialization:

```
httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;

string header = "Chrome/64.0.3282.140";
if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
}
```

I use this object for all request

But when I use it for POST request, it works like GET request or POST, but without parameters

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://some_websit.ru");
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pairs.Add("par1", "val1");
pairs.Add("par2", "val2");   
HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs)
var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, formContent);
string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It ignore parameters which I give.

I tried to send POST request here http://seriyps.ru/postget/ and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, I have tested it locally with the same code, only a different URL, and the POST request is sent properly along with the passed in parameters:

[image: me]

I recommend you to install [Telerik Fiddler 4](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to see the network traffic and confirm that the parameters are indeed sent. I have used `http://example.com` just as a sample URL here. I would suspect the problem is rather on the side of the server than your app or that the server expect different parameters than what is being sent.

Comment: Thanks for responde. I look at traffic in Telerik and understand, that I use Russian letter for value of parameter and it coded in some agly view like this 0%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: What specifically does not work in this case? In case the issue is different, create a new question and close this one in case this part is resolved.